# Unity Build Error Firebase : Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

When i import package play once a project then created firebase file in android folde then if i was going to build the app in android using window os it give me that error i try meni options change minimum and max api level combinathis, download diffrent version of unity with api level 2.01, or 4.0.x but it not allow me to build the APK file

[Unity Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZVrL.png)

i hade try most of the stack overflow option and also mail to firebase support but thary are givr mr same solutions

firebase provided solutio didnot work
I’m Audie with the Firebase Support Team, I’ll look into this and try to help you find a solution.

While checking this error message and looking for similar cases, it seems this is not related to the Firebase SDK, instead it is generated from local settings and it falls out of the [scope of Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/scope).

I’ll add some resources I believe can help you find a solution:

[Add Firebase to your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)
[Additional Unity installation options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup-alternative)
[Unity Storage Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/blob/main/storage/testapp/readme.md)

[StackOverflow - Unity build exception: Probably the SDK is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015013/unity-build-exception-probably-the-sdk-is-read-only)

Again, this is some unofficial advice given that this is not a problem generated from Firebase SDK.

- **File Permissions**: Make sure the user running Unity has the right permissions to change Android SDK files. If the files are locked, consider changing the permissions to allow modifications.
- **Anti-Virus or Security Software**: Sometimes, anti-virus or security programs can interfere with file operations, making them read-only. If this is the case, temporarily disable the security software and try again.
- **Unity Editor Permissions**: Confirm that the Unity Editor has the necessary permissions to change files in the Android SDK directory. Running Unity with administrative privileges may help in some cases.
- **File Locking**: Check if another process or application has locked the file package.xml, preventing Unity from making changes. Close any other applications that might be using the Android SDK files.
- **Unity Project Settings**: Review the Unity project settings related to Android SDK paths. Make sure the correct path to the Android SDK is set in Unity's preferences or project settings.

Comment: Hello, please paste those log errors as text by extracting them [from the log file directly](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039118331-I-have-been-asked-to-provide-a-log-file-where-do-I-find-this#:~:text=Windows%3A%20C%3A%5Cusers%5C%5Byourusername%5D%5CAppData%5CLocal%5C,log)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.